# Can I use microshift bar end shifters with 9-speed deore lx rear derailleur and 10-speed cassette?

Tags: derailleur, shifter

Can I use indexed 10-speed microshift bar end shifters (on [retroshift](http://retroshift.com) levers) with 9-speed deore lx rear derailleur and 10-speed 11-36 cassette? If not, What rear derailleur would work with the microshift shifters in indexed mode with this cassette?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as it's a 10s shifter with a 10s cassette it should work. Many derailleurs will work so long as they have enough chain capacity and they can fully extend to the highest and lowest gears